# How do Mashup Makers Get Access to the Separate Tracks?

Tags: pop-music

Mashups are pretty popular for music, such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYUbUl8onqg) that combines vocals from "Uptight" with elements of "Unchained." But in order to make these, it seems to me that the people would have to have access to separated tracks from the original (like Stevie Wonder's vocals without the original background music). How do they get those?

Comment: There's a very similar question here https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/41399/getting-multitracks-from-a-file/41400#41400 with an answer that covers basically everything except AI (which is a pretty new development)

Comment: haha - I'd forgotten I did that answer… anyway, here's a new, short version of the same thing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These have 'leaked' onto the interwebz by people reverse-engineering the 5-way stems from Games such as [Guitar Hero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guitar_Hero) etc.

Some others have been sourced from the actual original multitrack recordings & again 'leaked' into general availability.

The legitimacy of these is all very suspect. People seem to treat them as "so long as you get away with it…"

A third source is specifically aimed at remixers, official stems released by original artists on sites such as [RemixHub](https://www.mixinghub.com/all-open-contests/)

…and, as alluded to in the linked QA, you now can get some pretty smart AI software that can isolate aspects of a mix with reasonable accuracy. This is still pretty new technology, but is coming on in leaps & bounds. Such as [Izotope RX](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/rx.html) & others are starting to be able to do this to an acceptable degree.

Just cos I found it fun… this is a recent favourite of mine

Comment: Yeah, I like that one too.